# singleton constraint on a related model

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 models, model_A and model_B

There's a one to n relationship among them

One record in model_A has several related records in model_B

I'd like to introduce a constraint: only ONE related record in model_B can have one of its fields set to True

How do I express that ?

Comment: it's 1:n @LaurenzAlbe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's define sample tables:

```
CREATE TABLE model_a (
   a_id bigint PRIMARY KEY
);
                                                             ^
CREATE TABLE model_b (
   b_id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
   a_id bigint REFERENCES model_a NOT NULL,
   only_one_true boolean
);
```

Then you could create a unique index like

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON model_b (a_id, nullif(only_one_true, FALSE));
```

This will allow only one row per `a_id` where `only_one_true` is true:

```
INSERT INTO model_a VALUES (1), (2);
INSERT 0 2

INSERT INTO model_b VALUES (101, 1, FALSE);
INSERT 0 1
INSERT INTO model_b VALUES (102, 1, NULL);
INSERT 0 1
INSERT INTO model_b VALUES (103, 1, TRUE);
INSERT 0 1
INSERT INTO model_b VALUES (104, 1, FALSE);
INSERT 0 1
INSERT INTO model_b VALUES (105, 1, TRUE);
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "model_b_a_id_nullif_idx"
DETAIL:  Key (a_id, NULLIF(only_one_true, false))=(1, t) already exists.
INSERT INTO model_b VALUES (106, 1, NULL);
INSERT 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a filtered unique index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX OnlyOneTrue ON model_B
  (a_id)
WHERE (OnlyOneTrueColumn);
```

This approach works with both PostgreSQL and SQL Server.